# How to get TensorFlow source for canned models (Estimators)

Tags: python, tensorflow

We are using the canned dnn (tf.estimator.DNNClassifier and 
 tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier)(and others) estimators in TensorFlow 1.4 but are interested in inspecting and perhaps reimplementing the models with variations in native TensorFlow, as well as for learning purposes. Is there any way to do this or is it available in the docs? Or is there a way to see it in the source?

Comment: You can refer the below url for the source of TF 1.4 version of Canned Estimator<br>
[Canned Estimator with TF 1.4](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.4/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned)

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I needed! Thanks!